# See where function is defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxyquire

How can I see where this function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property

```
copyObject(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
```

**is defined?**

What I tried:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.S3.prototype.copyObject
=> undefined
```

But that is **undefined**

I want to know it because I want to stub this function with `proxyquire`:

```
 var aws_stub = {};
 var Mover =  proxyquire('../../callback/mover',
                         {'aws-sdk': aws_stub}
                         ).Mover;

 var fake_aws_copyObject = function(params, func){func(null, "succeed")};
     fake_aws_copyObject_stub = sinon.spy(fake_aws_copyObject);
     aws_stub.AWS.S3 ... ??   = fake_aws_copyObject_stub;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's specific to the version of the API you choose to use, so you have to create a new instance of your service first `var s3 = new AWS.S3();`.

You can find the definition of the service based on which it is generated somewhere in file describing the API: `aws-sdk/apis/s3-2006-03-01.min.json`.

The API files in `apis` are loaded in `lib/api_loader.js`.

You can see in `lib/service.js` that they are actually added to the prototype, but that only happens after you created a new instance of the service:

```
/**
 * Adds one method for each operation described in the api configuration
 *
 * @api private
 */
 defineMethods: function defineMethods(svc) {
     AWS.util.each(svc.prototype.api.operations, function iterator(method) {
         if (svc.prototype[method]) return;
         svc.prototype[method] = function (params, callback) {
             return this.makeRequest(method, params, callback);
         };
     });
 }
```